# How to list documents based on a variable?

Tags: couchdb

My use case is this:

- A user fill a form which creates a doc with his username stored.
- He goes to a certain URL, and it should lists all docs he created.

By googling and reading the documentation I've got simple design doc and view working, but I have no clue how to give it a variable and filter based on that (in that case, the username).
I've seen filter functions and wrote this in my view but it doesn't seem adapted to what I'm trying to do (and doesn't work anyway, blank result):

```
function (doc, req) {
  if (doc.author && doc.author === req.query.author) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I just can't find a solution online since all sites focus only on super simple static examples and avoid this case altogether.

The closest I got to a solution was to have a DB per user, but my app should also have an admin view which list documents of every users and interacts with them.

Comment: More generally from my answer, it sounds like you definitely should read the documentation more fully. It's confusing when you start, but I think you need to get the difference between filters and views down before you go much further :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't give views variables.

Think of views as a database index: they are a statically generated indexes into documents based on a chunk of JS that runs on each of your records and `emits()` things.

Your example code looks more like a filter than a view. You should definitely read the view guide from start to finish: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/intro.html

But basically what you're looking for is something like this:

```
function(doc) {
    emit(doc.where.the.author.name.is);
}
```

Then when you query the view you pass the author's name as a key to the view:

```
yourdb/_design/yourddoc/_view/yourview?key=authorname
```

This is just an example, *please* read the link above as views are a core concept of CouchDB and deserve to be understood well.